# The videos list from the device

Tags: android, listview, video, android-mediascanner

[image: local video list]

Hello

As you can tell, I'm interested to make a list of local video. scred that is by mediascan and ListView.
I found a tutorial but does not scan memory. in tutorial, the location is added manually
I would like something simple but automatically scan and display memory.
[tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/display-video-thumbnail-in-listview.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
File directory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/folder");

File[] files = directory.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
  if(files[i].getAbsolutePath().contains(".mp4"))
    paths.add(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me what to do with this code? thank you. I replaced that string of code and does not work, started receiving error.